# Python's asyncore to periodically send data using a variable timeout. Is there a better way?

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous

I wanted to write a server that a client could connect to and receive periodic updates without having to poll.  The problem I have experienced with asyncore is that if you do not return true when dispatcher.writable() is called, you have to wait until after the asyncore.loop has timed out (default is 30s).

The two ways I have tried to work around this is 1) reduce timeout to a low value or 2) query connections for when they will next update and generate an adequate timeout value.  However if you refer to 'Select Law' in 'man 2 select_tut', it states, "You should always try to use select() without a timeout."

Is there a better way to do this?  Twisted maybe?  I wanted to try and avoid extra threads.  I'll include the variable timeout example here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import socket
import asyncore


# in seconds
UPDATE_PERIOD = 4.0

class Channel(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, sock, sck_map):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, sock=sock, map=sck_map)
        self.last_update = 0.0  # should update immediately
        self.send_buf = ''
        self.recv_buf = ''

    def writable(self):
        return len(self.send_buf) > 0

    def handle_write(self):
        nbytes = self.send(self.send_buf)
        self.send_buf = self.send_buf[nbytes:]

    def handle_read(self):
        print 'read'
        print 'recv:', self.recv(4096)

    def handle_close(self):
        print 'close'
        self.close()

    # added for variable timeout
    def update(self):
        if time.time() >= self.next_update():
            self.send_buf += 'hello %f\n'%(time.time())
            self.last_update = time.time()

    def next_update(self):
        return self.last_update + UPDATE_PERIOD


class Server(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, port, sck_map):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, map=sck_map)
        self.port = port
        self.sck_map = sck_map
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.bind( ("", port))
        self.listen(16)
        print "listening on port", self.port

    def handle_accept(self):
        (conn, addr) = self.accept()
        Channel(sock=conn, sck_map=self.sck_map)

    # added for variable timeout
    def update(self):
        pass

    def next_update(self):
        return None


sck_map = {}

server = Server(9090, sck_map)
while True:
    next_update = time.time() + 30.0
    for c in sck_map.values():
        c.update()  # <-- fill write buffers
        n = c.next_update()
        #print 'n:',n
        if n is not None:
            next_update = min(next_update, n)
    _timeout = max(0.1, next_update - time.time())

    asyncore.loop(timeout=_timeout, count=1, map=sck_map)
```

Comment: Nick:Which is the small change to make it function? Could you put the code? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "select law" doesn't apply to your case, as you have not only client-triggered (pure server) activities, but also time-triggered activities - this is precisely what the select timeout is for. What the law should really say is "if you specify a timeout, make sure you actually have to do something useful when the timeout arrives". The law is meant to protect against busy-waiting; your code does not busy-wait.

I would not set _timeout to the maximum of 0.1 and the next update time, but to the maximum of 0.0 and the next timeout. IOW, if an update period has expired while you were doing updates, you should do that specific update right away.

Instead of asking each channel every time whether it wants to update, you could store all channels in a priority queue (sorted by next-update time), and then only run update for the earliest channels (until you find one whose update time has not arrived). You can use the heapq module for that.

You can also save a few system calls by not having each channel ask for the current time, but only poll the current time once, and pass it to .update.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can do this with `sched.scheduler`, like this (n.b. not tested):

```
import sched, asyncore, time

# Create a scheduler with a delay function that calls asyncore.loop
scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, lambda t: _poll_loop(t, time.time()) )

# Add the update timeouts with scheduler.enter
# ...

def _poll_loop(timeout, start_time):  
  asyncore.loop(timeout, count=1)
  finish_time = time.time()
  timeleft = finish_time - start_time
  if timeleft > timeout:  # there was a message and the timeout delay is not finished
    _poll_loop(timeleft, finish_time) # so wait some more polling the socket

def main_loop():
  while True:
    if scheduler.empty():
      asyncore.loop(30.0, count=1) # just default timeout, use what suits you
      # add other work that might create scheduled events here
    else:
      scheduler.run()
```

Comment: While this answer is nice, you will soon run in a RuntimeError with recursion depth in _poll_loop. Better write it without recursion for real world examples. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is basically demiurgus' solution with the rough edges made round. It retains his basic idea, but prevents RuntimeErrors and busy loops and is tested. [Edit: resolved issues with modifying the scheduler during _delay]

```
class asynschedcore(sched.scheduler):
    """Combine sched.scheduler and asyncore.loop."""
    # On receiving a signal asyncore kindly restarts select. However the signal
    # handler might change the scheduler instance. This tunable determines the
    # maximum time in seconds to spend in asycore.loop before reexamining the
    # scheduler.
    maxloop = 30
    def __init__(self, map=None):
        sched.scheduler.__init__(self, time.time, self._delay)
        if map is None:
            self._asynmap = asyncore.socket_map
        else:
            self._asynmap = map
        self._abort_delay = False

    def _maybe_abort_delay(self):
        if not self._abort_delay:
            return False
        # Returning from this function causes the next event to be executed, so
        # it might be executed too early. This can be avoided by modifying the
        # head of the queue. Also note that enterabs sets _abort_delay to True.
        self.enterabs(0, 0, lambda:None, ())
        self._abort_delay = False
        return True

    def _delay(self, timeout):
        if self._maybe_abort_delay():
            return
        if 0 == timeout:
            # Should we support this hack, too?
            # asyncore.loop(0, map=self._asynmap, count=1)
            return
        now = time.time()
        finish = now + timeout
        while now < finish and self._asynmap:
            asyncore.loop(min(finish - now, self.maxloop), map=self._asynmap,
                          count=1)
            if self._maybe_abort_delay():
                return
            now = time.time()
        if now < finish:
            time.sleep(finish - now)

    def enterabs(self, abstime, priority, action, argument):
        # We might insert an event before the currently next event.
        self._abort_delay = True
        return sched.scheduler.enterabs(self, abstime, priority, action,
                                        argument)

    # Overwriting enter is not necessary, because it is implemented using enter.

    def cancel(self, event):
        # We might cancel the next event.
        self._abort_delay = True
        return sched.scheduler.cancel(self, event)

    def run(self):
        """Runs as long as either an event is scheduled or there are
        sockets in the map."""
        while True:
            if not self.empty():
                sched.scheduler.run(self)
            elif self._asynmap:
                asyncore.loop(self.maxloop, map=self._asynmap, count=1)
            else:
                break
```

Comment: Have only done limited testing, but seems to work great!

Answer (score 1):

I would use Twisted, long time since I used asyncore but I think this should be the twisted equivalent (not tested, written from memory):

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
import time

UPDATE_PERIOD = 4.0

class MyClient(protocol.Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.updateCall = reactor.callLater(UPDATE_PERIOD, self.update)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.updateCall.cancel()

    def update(self):
        self.transport.write("hello %f\n" % (time.time(),))

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "recv:", data


f = protocol.ServerFactory()
f.protocol = MyClient

reactor.listenTCP(9090, f)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Code works (pretty good if from memory!) but needed a small change to call reactor.callLater() in the update() method to send the next update.  Otherwise you only get one message and the updateCall.cancel() will fail on disconnection.

My only problem is that twisted adds an extra dependency but I will have to weigh this against actual productivity and readability.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand what the OP was trying to accomplish, but I just solved this issue using 1 thread that gets a weakref of each Channel(asyncore.dispatcher) object.  This thread determines its own timing and will send the Channel an update periodically using a Queue in that channel.  It gets the Queue from the Channel object by calling getQueue.

The reason I use a weakref is because clients are transient.  If the channel dies then the weakref returns None.  That way the timing thread doesn't keep old objects alive because it references them.

I know the OP wanted to avoid threads, but this solution is very simple. It only ever creates one thread and it talks to any Channels that are created as the Server object adds them to the threads list of objects to monitor.